# Rails link_to raise no route matches error only when rendering from JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got Presentations and comments, each presentation allow many comments and those comments can by replied so...

On my presentation show, I render comments successfully this way:

```
  <div id= "container_comments">
    <%= render @presentation.comments.where(ancestry: nil) %>
  </div>
```

this way all comments are rendered using this base _comment.html.erb file:

```
<div class="media" id="comment_<%= comment.id %>">
      <div class="media-left">
        <img src="<%= image_path("comment.png")%>" class="media-object" style="width:45px">
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><%=User.find(comment.author_id).username%> <small><i>Publicado: <%=comment.created_at.strftime('%F %T') %></i></small></h4>
        <p><%=comment.body%></p>
      

        <%= link_to "Reply", new_comment_congress_category_presentation_comment_path(@congress, @category, @presentation, :parent_id => comment ), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#mynewcomment"%>
      
        <% replies = Comment.where(ancestry: comment) %>
        <% if replies.any? %>
          <% replies.each do |reply| %>
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <img src="<%= image_path("reply.png")%>" class="media-object" style="width:45px">
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading"><%=User.find(reply.author_id).username%> <small><i>Publicado: <%=reply.created_at.strftime('%F %T') %></i></small></h4>
                <p><%=reply.body%></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <%end%>
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Everything works fine here, presentation loads comments and replies properly, the problem is that the reply's link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_comment_congress_category_presentation_comment_path(@congress, @category, @presentation, :parent_id => comment ), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#mynewcomment"%>
```

which loads correctly from the presentation show view does not allow rendering from JS files, it shows "no route matches " error with missing key [:id].

Here's my js file:

```
$("#mynewcomment").modal('hide');
$(".comment_title").val('');
$(".comment_content").val('');
<%if @comment.parent == nil%>
  $("#container_comments").append('<%= j render @comment %>');
  $("#comment_<%= @comment.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);
<%else%>
   <%@parent = Comment.find(@comment.parent_id)%>
   $("#comment_<%= @parent.id %>").replaceWith('<%= j render @parent %>');
<%end%>
```

And here is how the error looks like:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"new_comment", :category_id=>#<...category info here...>, :congress_id=>#<...congress info here...>, :controller=>"comments", :parent_id=>#<...parent comment info here...>, :presentation_id=>#<...Presentation info here...>}, missing required keys: [:id]):
 7:             <p><%=comment.body%></p>
 8:
 9:
10:             <%= link_to "Responder", new_comment_congress_category_presentation_comment_path(@congress, @category, @presentation, :parent_id => comment), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#mynewcomment", :parent_id => comment %>
11:
12:             <% replies = Comment.where(ancestry: comment) %>
13:             <% if replies.any? %>

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:10:in 
`_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb__456499711_134033424'
app/views/comments/create.js.erb:5:in 
`_app_views_comments_create_js_erb__184660212_140959668'
```

I wonder how the exact same file fails to render through js .... I really appreciate your help, this is the only step for finishing my first rails project, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since your link depends on the `@congress`, `@category` and `@presentation` variables, you have to make sure that these same variables are made available for the JS template as well.

To make this kind of mistake harder to make, you can change your template to use **local variables** instead of instance variables, using the `locals` hash:

```
# in _comment.html.erb
<%=
  link_to "Reply",
    new_comment_congress_category_presentation_comment_path(
      congress, category, presentation,
      parent_id: comment
    )
%>

# in show.html.erb
<%=
  render @presentation.comments.where(ancestry: nil),
    locals: { congress: @congress, category: @category, presentation: @presentation }
%>

# in whatever.js.erb
<%= j render @comment, locals: { congress: @congress, ... } %>
```

This way, if you fail to assign even a single one of the three required local variables, the error message will explicitly tell you which one is missing.